# C# audio and visual streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, directx

Trying to find code to basically stream audio and visual streams over a network can't find proper examples to firmly get a good understanding of how best to approach the development. I've looked at direct sound and Direct X examples but nothing has been concrete enough. Trying to basically create a web page in C# that will be able to stream audio and visual to users. Any help or references will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If silverlight is an option to use that will solve a lot of the problems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189078(v=vs.95).aspx

Found a good tutorial as well:
http://www.learn-silverlight-tutorial.com/StreamingMediaUsingSilverlight.cfm

Comment: thanks steven, however i'm trying to look at all the different options.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding audio streaming, check out [Bass.NET](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html)